# c++ how to check -1.#IND in array

Tags: c++, floating-point

I got a float array which stores some value thats been calculated by some functions. However, when I retrieve a value from the array, some of the values are -1.#IND, which is a float error or some sort i guess.

So heres my little question, how do I use a if statement to check if the float array contains a -1.#IND value so I can do something with it??

Thanks

Comment: Interesting solution. Does optimization just know to never eliminate the comparison if the value is a float?

Comment: @mah that would be a well written optimizer, i.e., one that doesn't make false assumptions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if(a != a); 
This is only true if a is a NaN.
Oh, and also in cmath there is a isnan() function.
[More About isnan()...](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan)

Comment: Wow, I never knew a != a when a is not a number!

Answer (score 2):

-1.#IND is a NaN code (not a number) in that the value is undefined / unrepresentable. So your numerical algorithm might have an issue if it's producing NaN values. Check that floating point exceptions are turned on as NaN's can result from division by 0 errors and make sure you're running it in debug mode, step through and see when, how and why it occurs.

Not sure whether you can do a direct equality comparison as the representation can change,

check IEEE 754, also check that your compiler is using IEEE 754 floats.

Hope this helps.

Comment: NaNs are never equal to anything, even to itself.

Answer (score 1):

`-1.#IND` looks like the "indefinite" value, which will come up if you do things like try to calculate 0/0.

Other values you might encounter are positive and negative infinity.

To filter out these special values, use functions like `_finite`, `finitef` or `_fpclass`.

Comment: For C++11 or C99, you'd use `fpclassify`. The other methods are pre-standard.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to check if a floating point value is a valid number is to use: std::isnormal() 
If the number is not normal, you can use std::fpclassify() to figure out which error it is.